# Creating new Master Page with UI version 16 inside my Sharepoint server 2016 , does not have any effect

Tags: development, master-page, custom-masterpage, 2016

I am starting a new sharepoint server 2016 on-premise project, and i install February 2017 CU.
now i have noted that new site collections still comes with the old `seatle.master` & `osolo.master` master pages and they are set to 15 UI version, as follow:-

[image]

now i wanted to create  a new custom master page for my site collections, so i follow these steps which i use to follow in SP 2013:-

1. i download a copy from `seatle.master`
2. rename the copy to `ARQ.master`.
3. Uplaod the new `ARQ.master` master page.
4. i defined the UI version to be 16, as follow:-
   [image]
5. publish the new master page.
6. then from SP designer i try to set the new master page as defualt and as custom master page, where i got this warning message and i click ok:-
   [image]
7. now i can not notice any update to the UI fro my site collection pages and interfaces, and even when i access "site settings >> master Page" i can not find the new master page :-

[image]

so can anyone advice what is the story ??
Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SharePoint 2016 uses the UI Version 15, not 16.

Comment: The question regards SP 2016

Comment: @Michael i am asking about about sharepoint 2016 .. the case i mentioned is inside SP 2016..

Comment: This answer is *also* correct for SharePoint 2016. Use UI Version 15.

Comment: @TrevorSeward so currently there is not a real 16 UI for SP 2016 ??

Comment: And there won't be. This was a strategic choice to prevent massive UI upgrade investments that were required when migrating from one version of SharePoint to another in the past. This also matches up with SPO where there is no UI change (it's all V15).

Comment: Sorry; I missed that - but thanks Trevor for the clarification.